# cakephp no such file or directory

Tags: php, cakephp

I have no knowledge on PHP and I try to install a php web and it shows this error:

> **Notice: Use of undefined constant CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH** - assumed 'CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH' in /usr/local/crowdfunding/app/webroot/test.php on line 79 Warning: include(Cake/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/crowdfunding/app/webroot/test.php on line 91 Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Cake/bootstrap.php' for inclusion (include_path='/usr/local/crowdfunding/lib:CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/local/crowdfunding/app/:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /usr/local/crowdfunding/app/webroot/test.php on line 91 Fatal error: CakePHP core could not be found. Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php. It should point to the directory containing your /cake core directory and your /vendors root directory. in /usr/local/crowdfunding/app/webroot/test.php on line 100

**On test.php: (cakephp test):**

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
/**
 * Use the DS to separate the directories in other defines
 */
    if (!defined('DS')) {
        define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    }
/**
 * These defines should only be edited if you have cake installed in
 * a directory layout other than the way it is distributed.
 * When using custom settings be sure to use the DS and do not add a trailing DS.
 */

/**
 * The full path to the directory which holds "app", WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 */
    if (!defined('ROOT')) {
        define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
    }
/**
 * The actual directory name for the "app".
 *
 */
    if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
        define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
    }
        if (!defined('WEBROOT_DIR')) {
        define('WEBROOT_DIR', basename(dirname(__FILE__)));
    }
    if (!defined('WWW_ROOT')) {
        define('WWW_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DS);
    }
    if (!defined('CORE_PATH')) {
        if (function_exists('ini_set') && ini_set('include_path', CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'))) {
            define('APP_PATH', null);
            define('CORE_PATH', null);
        } else {
            define('APP_PATH', ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS);
            define('CORE_PATH', CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS);
        }
    }
    if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
        if (function_exists('ini_set')) {
            ini_set('include_path', ROOT . DS . 'lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'));
        }
        if (!include('Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) {
            $failed = true;
        }
    } else {
        if (!include(CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS . 'Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) {
            $failed = true;
        }
    }
    if (!empty($failed)) {
        trigger_error("CakePHP core could not be found.  Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php.  It should point to the directory containing your " . DS . "cake core directory and your " . DS . "vendors root directory.", E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    if (Configure::read('debug') < 1) {
        die(__d('cake_dev', 'Debug setting does not allow access to this url.'));
    }

    require_once CAKE . 'TestSuite' . DS . 'CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php';

    CakeTestSuiteDispatcher::run();
```

**File Structure:**

```
Config/config.php 
       bootstrap.php
        ...
webroot/test.php
```

It seems that it cannot search for Config folder out there. What should I do to get it to work ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the index.php file and see where CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH points to... you might need to copy the line over to the test.php file.

ie: `define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'lib');`